# How to pass variables from one PHP file to another using HTML links?

Tags: php, mysql, reference

```
    //DB CONNECTION
   $sql = "SELECT `city`,`country` from infotab";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo  $row["city"].$row["country"]"<a href='order.php'>order</a>"; }
```

Table output:

[image: http://imgur.com/jH2VzBf]

This code will select data. Additionally, there is reference to `order.php` on every line. When the user clicks on reference( `<a href>` clause), it opens `order.php` and there I need to know which row the user selected to work with these data.

Comment: Do you have a id column in your db? yes, why not use the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {         
    echo  $row["city"] . $row["country"] . "<a href='order.php?city=" . $row["city"] . "&country=" . $row["country"] . "'>order</a>";
}
```

In `order.php` you can then access these values by using the `$_GET["city"]` and `$_GET["country"]` variables which contain the values from your `<a href>` link on the previous page. For example, running `echo $_GET["city"];` will output the city name.

**Edit:** As @Rizier123 pointed out, using a unique ID might be more prone to errors in case your database contains more than one entry for the same city or country. You should consider introducing an ID in your table structure and then using that in the link to `order.php`.

Comment: I doubt that the city is a unique column in OP's db!

Comment: You may have a point. Anyway, we don't know that and the combination of city and country could be unique. @Martin: Please clarify.

Comment: That's what I'm already asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876269/php-references-to-other-files-using-data-from-database/29876353?noredirect=1#comment47876789_29876269 (In other words, your solution can work if OP uses something unique to identify the row)

Comment: These data aren t unique, but i ll try to implement ids.

Comment: This tutorial could help you --> [MySQL Primary Key](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/)